# Code crashing after using formatting

Tags: java, number-formatting

I'm new to the Java language (Just started about 2 weeks ago)

Basically, the user enters their year/month/day they were born on in order and I use this information to perform a math calculation that will show their age.

I need numbers from 0-9 to be taken in as 01, 02, 03... So, I searched around and found that I can use Decimal.Format and then print out the format later on.

My code crashes whenever it reaches the println(twodigits.format) part no mater where I put it. There are no errors displayed that I need to address.

Why is it doing this and is there a better way to do this? I need it to be 2 digits at all times or the calculation won't work.

Here's a part of my code, I can provide more if needed.

```
DecimalFormat twodigits = new DecimalFormat("00");
System.out.println("Calculating...");

Integer CurrentDate2 = Integer.valueOf(CurrentDate);
Integer BirthDate2 = Integer.valueOf(BirthDate);

int a = CurrentDate2.intValue();
int b = BirthDate2.intValue();
int age = (a - b) / 1000;
Thread.sleep(300);
System.out.println(".");
Thread.sleep(300);
System.out.println(".");
Thread.sleep(300);
System.out.println(".");
System.out.println(twodigits.format(CurrentDate));
System.out.println(twodigits.format(BirthDate));
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing `CurrentDate` and `BirthDate` are `String`s? `DecimalFormat.format()` expects a number value.

Comment: If you are taking input from the user/keyboard, you can start with a Scanner object.

Comment: "You need it to be two digits are the calculations don't work," I am confused?

Answer (score 0):

What types are "CurrentDate" and "BirthDate" because it's not clear from your code?  You first use them to set "CurrentDate2" and "BirthDate2".  And then you use them in the println().

If I were to guess, I'd say they are of type 'String', and 'twodigits.format()' can't handle Strings, which is why it's crashing.

Answer (score 0):

This takes two dates and split time on "/". It then prints them out in the format that you want.

```
    DecimalFormat twodigits = new DecimalFormat("00");
    System.out.println("Calculating...");

    String CurrentDate = "01/02/2007";
    String BirthDate = "02/03/2007";

    String[] currentDateParts = CurrentDate.split("/");
    String[] birthDateParts = BirthDate.split("/");

    int cdp0 = Integer.parseInt(currentDateParts[0]);
    int cdp1 = Integer.parseInt(currentDateParts[1]);
    int cdp2 = Integer.parseInt(currentDateParts[2]);


    int bdp0 = Integer.parseInt(birthDateParts[0]);
    int bdp1 = Integer.parseInt(birthDateParts[1]);
    int bdp2 = Integer.parseInt(birthDateParts[2]);

    //do your calculations

    System.out.println(twodigits.format(cdp0));
    System.out.println(twodigits.format(cdp1));
    System.out.println(twodigits.format(cdp2));
    System.out.println(twodigits.format(bdp0));
    System.out.println(twodigits.format(bdp1));
    System.out.println(twodigits.format(bdp2));
```